# Inconsistency in the official Java EE 7 tutorial about JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have been studying the official Java EE 7 tutorial. I am confused by the following statement from [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs002.htm):

> Methods decorated with request method designators must return void, a
>   Java programming language type, or a javax.ws.rs.core.Response object.

On the same page, there is this sample method:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String getHtml() {
    return "<html lang=\"en\"><body><h1>Hello, World!!</h1></body></html>";
}
```

The example above clearly violates the aforementioned statement, since it returns `String` rather than `void` or `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`. So, is this an error or am I missing anything here? Thank you in advance.

## Update

It's my mistake. I thought the `a java programming language type` was explaining that `void` was a java programming language type. My bad.

Comment: I think perhaps the problem here lies in what is meant by Java programming language type.  Does that only mean primitives, or does it also encompass types built into the API like String, Double, Integer, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in the documentation, the fact that a method annotared with method designator returns void, Java type, or Response, depend on your intention , by instance if you have a method annotared with `@Post` method designator you have the option to notify the caller the result of operation or not. that all depend that you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.String is a valid Java programming language type, nothing is violated as far as I can see